# Redmine - How to implement Single Sign-On solution using OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, omniauth, redmine

I'm currently trying to implement a Single Sign-On solution on a Redmine installation (Version: 2.5, Rails: 3.2, Ruby: 1.9) using OmniAuth. Can anyone give me some advices on the best way to make it work? Thank you!

Comment: Share your code that you have tried for this. If you have not tried anything yet, try it first

Comment: May be will help you http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/ and http://sysmagazine.com/posts/189410/

Comment: Those are great articles! I will take a look and try those approaches on my application. Thank you!